# Redirect exact url

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I'm using the following directives in .htaccess to redirect only example.com/script-dir/index.php (with www and without) to example.com/index.php.  But it also redirects example.com/script-dir/index.php?page=faq and other pages.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^script\-dir\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

What should I do to redirect only that single page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string (`?page=faq`) isn't part of the URL that gets tested in the RewriteRule, so you have to add a separate condition to test it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^script-dir/index\.php$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure why other pages would get redirected though.

Answer (score 0):

You can RewriteCond based on empty QUERY_STRING, following same approach as in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591367/4363163 . Also, you might prefer exact match, without relying on RegExp, as explained in this other answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24476841/4363163